# Error: Missing required in WordPress Divi Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, google-search-console

I have this ongoing issue with my divi theme. I don't know how to fix this and I've been reading around and tried different things but can't seem to find something that works with the Divi theme.

Extracted structured data error message I'm getting from WebMaster:

```
Error: Missing required field "entry-title".
Error: Missing required field "updated".
Error: Missing required hCard "author".
```

Please specify where I need to go and what I need to change (example: Divi > single.php > and so forth). I sometimes get answers and I don't know what to modify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have updated this for http://flyeasy.org.in and the solution is to create a new user mentioning him as Author in Admin Access, then open a page and go to screen option and select author. Now in the page check for author and update it with the new author user which you already created.

Hope this answers your query.

Comment: Thanks Avin. I made the changes. Let's see if this will fix this issue. By the way, happy new year.